# symfony fixtures: set ondelete: CASCADE on refclass table

Tags: mysql, symfony1, doctrine, fixtures

I'm using symfony 1.4.5, Doctrine 1.2 and Mysql 5.

In my schema.yml I have a few Many-to-Many relations which work great. But I need the joining table to have onDelete: CASCADE.

Now for doctrine it is needed to add onDelete: CASCADE on the side where the foreignkey exists but since the refclass does not have any relations in the schema.yml I can't.

example schema:

```
Organisatie:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: organisatie
   columns:
    org_id:
     type: integer(4)
     fixed: false
     unsigned: false
     primary: true
     autoincrement: true
   naam:
     type: string(30)
     fixed: false
     unsigned: false
     primary: false
     notnull: true
     autoincrement: false
   relations:
     Sc:
      class: Sc
      refClass: ScRegel
      local: org_id
      foreign: sc_id

Sc:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sc
  columns:
    sc_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
      notnull: true
    sc_nummer:
      type: string(15)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
      notnull: true
    type:
      type: string(20)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: true
      autoincrement: false
  relations:
    Organisatie:
      class: Organisatie
      refClass: ScRegel
      local: sc_id
      foreign: org_id

 ScRegel:
  connection: doctrine
  tableName: sc_regel
  columns:
    sc_id:
      type: integer(4)
      primary: true
      autoincrement: true
      notnull: true
    sc_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      autoincrement: false
      notnull: true
    org_id:
      type: integer(4)
      fixed: false
      unsigned: false
      primary: false
      notnull: false
      autoincrement: false
```

Now i tried to add onDelete: CASCADE on both sides (Sc and Organisatie), but in both cases they are ignored, the relation is made, but the onDelete is ignored.

Does anybody know how to get this working?

Comment: Does both tables use InnoDB storage engine?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Yes :) mywhole database is setup using InnoDB, also the relation is working fine, only the cascade thing is not transfered.

Comment: Could you paste an output of SHOW CREATE TABLE sc; ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Q3mGL3xA ;)

Comment: also for the sc_regel table: http://pastebin.com/1rhFm6qL

note the extra fields, i left them out in my example since their not really important to the question

Comment: I don't see onDelete: CASCADE in your schema. Maybe you put them to wrong locations?

Comment: I tried adding them both to the the Sc relation and the Organisation table, but it has no effect whatsoever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually my original answer is in correct. Here is how I do it in an application I am building.

So UserSearch has a m-m join table called SearchTag. But I want to cascade my deletes of UserSearch to the SearchTag table.

So I explicitly define the relationship to SearchTag and put the cascade on that realtionship.

I don't like using ondelete as it means you can break things in phpmyadmin etc, so using "cascade: [delete]" means all the deletes are handled by the application.

```
UserSearch:
  actAs: [Timestampable]
  columns:
    user_id:
      type: integer(4)
    update_minutes: integer(4)
    last_ran: integer
    next_run: integer
    running: boolean
  relations:
    Tags:
      class: Tag
      local: search_id
      foreign: tag_id
      refClass: SearchTag
    SearchTags:
      local: id
      foreign: search_id
      class: SearchTag
      type: many
      foreignType: one
      cascade: [delete]

SearchTag:
  columns:
    search_id: 
      type: integer
      primary: true
    tag_id: 
      type: integer
      primary: true

Tag:
  columns:
    name: {type: string(255), notnull: true}
  relations:
    Searches:
      class: UserSearch
      local: tag_id
      foreign: search_id
      refClass: SearchTag
    SearchTags:
      local: id
      foreign: tag_id
      class: SearchTag
      type: many
      foreignType: one
      cascade: [delete]
```

Comment: Your solution works but I don't understand why we can't simply add the `delete: [cascade]` instruction to the both side of the existing relation instead of creating a new relation (which I don't understand neither)?